# adding highlight to parts of a regexp

Tags: regular-expressions, font-lock

I am pretty new to emacs so please excuse the rookie question.

So I am editing a helm chart template, and have enabled `yaml-mode` since most of helm uses yaml.

but I wanted to add some highlighting to the helm specific parts.

so for example

```
metadata:
  name: {{.name}}
```

I wanted `{{.name}}` to be highlighted which was easy enough

```
(add-hook 'yaml-mode-hook '(lambda ()
  (highlight-regexp "{{[^-].*?}}" font-lock-constant-face)
))
```

but I am having issues with the if statements.
for example

```
{{- if .configMap }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
```

I want the if part to be highlighted, but nothing else. in other words, highlight `if`, don't highlight `.configMap`

I thought it should be possible with a positive lookbehind, but sounded like that is not possible with an Emacs Lisp regexp.

How can I highlight only the `if` part?

Answer (score 0):

I think `(regexp-opt '("if") 'words)` will generate a regexp that does what you want.

(Node [Regexp Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Functions.html) of the Emacs manual documents functions that help you generate regexps.)